# Correctly writing sech^2 function in 3D

Tags: geometry, functions, trigonometry

I'm looking to analyse some data for measuring the duration of short laser pulses. The distribution of the data on my CCD camera should be a $sech^{2}$ function in 3D. I could pick the axes myself and apply a $sech^{2}$ fit to both x and y independently but I want to be more robust and apply a 3-dimensional fit over the whole image. Before I start writing a code to analyse the data, I want to first be sure that the model is correct.

A 2D sech2 takes the form:

$A = \frac{A_{0}}{cosh^{2}((x-x_{0})/\tau)}$

Where $sech^{2} = 1/cosh^{2}$, $A_{0}$ is the amplitude and $\tau$ is the width of the distribution. $x_{0}$ is the position of the peak of the fit relative to the origin of the x axis.

So taking inspiration from the wikipedia page for the [Gaussian distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function#Two-dimensional_Gaussian_function) and looking at how the 2D and 3D distributions differ, I tried writing the equation in 3D as:

$A = \frac{A_{0}}{(cosh((x-x_{0})/\tau_{x}) + (cosh((y-y_{0})/\tau_{y}) )^{2}}$

When I plot these functions with arbitrary coefficients, the 2D and 3D distributions do not agree. For the 3D distribution: the amplitude is to small by a factor of 4 and the width of the distribution is too large.

What is is that I am doing wrong here?
How do I correctly write the equation for a three-dimensional $sech^{2}$ function?

Comment: Your problem is that the Gaussian formula exploits properties specific only to exponentials, namely that multiplying them adds their powers. Really what you want is for your argument to expressed in terms of the total Euclidean distance (after you've adjusted for whatever factors you want).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding on to my comment, I suggest using this form for your higher dimensional sech:

$$A = \frac{A_0}{\cosh^2\left(\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{(x_i-x_{i0})^2}{\tau_i^2}}\right)}$$

And specifically for your 2D case (where I'm referring to the number of variables, not where its graph lives) we have

$$A=A_0\hspace{3 pt}\text{sech}^2\hspace{2 pt}\left(\sqrt{\frac{(x-x_0)^2}{\tau_x^2}+\frac{(y-y_0)^2}{\tau_y^2}}\right)$$

Comment: Thank you! This is working for me. I think I understand the difference between the Gauss and the sech. Would the method I used initially work if I used Eulers formula to re-write the trig functions in exponential form?

Comment: @LewisReid I think making it look different wouldn't fix the original problem, but maybe it could be rewritten once in exp form? But the problem still persists of the beam profile not being in terms of Euclidean distance in the original equation. On a more philosophical note, you wouldn't happen to be hiring? I've been looking for a job in plasma physics, unless you're working with a university.